# WooCommerce AJAX update and delete buttons (outside of cart page)

Tags: ajax, woocommerce

I have a cart list in my header, so it's outside of the actual cart page. In it, I have buttons to update and delete each cart item. It works fine, but my issue is that I'm trying to use AJAX to get rid of the page refresh.

So far I have the following

```js
$('.cart-list form').on('submit', function() {

    var $theForm = $(this);

    // send xhr request
    $.post({
      type: $theForm.attr('method'),
      url: $theForm.attr('action'),
      data: $theForm.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        // This works
        console.log("success!")
        });
      }
    });

    // prevent submitting again
    return false;

  });
```

I got that snippet from another stack overflow post. That user was doing a similar thing, but for adding a new product. To get it to work, he needed to add a hidden input inside of his form.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $id ); ?>" />
```

Of course, that won't work for me, since I'm not just adding to cart. I'm updating the quantity or deleting the product altogether.

Are there any other hidden inputs I should try adding to my form to get this to work, or anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Place this input by the update button

```
<input type="hidden" name="update_cart" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
```

To do delete, use the following

```js
$('YOURDELETEBUTTON').on('click', function() {
    
    var href = $(this).prop('href');

    // send xhr request
    $.post({
      type: 'post',
      url: href,
      success: function(data) {
        // Maybe add a document trigger here
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
```